# In which episodes of Star Trek TNG were 'new life' encountered?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

This is not just a new species to the crew, but also new to the viewer. I remember in TNG that there were several new aliens; Q, Nagilum, etc.

What other *"aliens"* did the crew encounter? This would be anything that was a creature who was sentient, another lifeform which had to interact in some way with a character, that might have displayed an ability or an influence or something that says "*Hey, I could be a threat!*"

**Hallucinations or the crew being transformed into things don't count.**

I'm especially interested in species where communication between the lifeform and the crew was possible or if the lifeform was otherwise a threat

Comment: you're asking "which episodes introduced a new alien race"?

Comment: Do you count events like when Kirk was split into two?  How about where Neelix and Tuvok merged into one?  There's a WIDE range of things that can qualify as 'new life'...this question is far too broad.

Comment: I feel like making a list of episodes without "new life" encounters might be easier.

Comment: Might be a good idea to focus on one series and specific criteria for "new life". Keep in mind that DS9 and Voyagers mission statements did not include seeking out new life and civilizations.

Comment: Not trying to be funny pretty much 80% of Voyager episodes fits this. Enterprise as well.

Comment: @Valorum as much as I dislike them, large but well-scoped lists are established as on-topic ([1](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2868/3267), [2](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10399/3267), [3](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2639/3267), [4](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17/3267)). There are only 726 released episodes, not all of which qualify. If you don't like it, go make a meta post and determine a max population size.

Comment: I'm always curious about questions like this: what are you going to **do** with this information?

Comment: @KevinWorkman - Win arguments the next time someone in the pub says "*Yeah, but they hardly ever encountered new life...*"

Comment: Just a fun read. The point of Star Trek itself I thought was to seek out new life-was curious what episodes had new life than just the interactions

Comment: @Valorum Interesting. The help center says that "mindless social fun" is off topic: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: @KevinWorkman - Yeah, but we tend to ignore that because the person/people who wrote it are a bunch of joyless b*stards.

Comment: @Valorum Haha fair enough. I guess my point is that we should maybe update the help center if at all possible, but I digress.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Taking into account only those episodes where the crew of the Enterprise-D encounter **a wholly new lifeform** or **uncover one that was previously hidden**, the crew succeed in their mission to "seek out new life" on no less than 37 occasions.

<sub>Where the species is sentient, they're marked with an (s). Where they're malevolent, they're marked with a (m)</sub>

### Season 1

**Encounter at Farpoint, Part I:** The Q (m)(s)
**Encounter at Farpoint, Part II:** Two unnamed warp-capable jellyfish (s)
**Lonely Among Us:** Unnamed energy lifeform (s)
**Justice:** The Edo(s) and their unnamed god (s)
**Datalore:** The Crystalline Entity (m)(s)
**When The Bough Breaks:** The Aldeans (s)
**Home Soil:** Unnamed Silicon-based lifeform (s)
**Skin of Evil:** Armus (m)(s)
**Conspiracy:** Unnamed Parasitic lifeform (m)

### Season 2

**The Child:** Unnamed energy lifeform (s)
**Where Silence Has Lease:** Nagilum (m)(s)
**Pen Pals:** The Dremans (s)
**Q Who:** The Borg (m)(s)
**Shades of Gray:** Unnamed Alien Parasite (m)

### Season 3

**Evolution:** Wesley's Nanites (s)
**Deja Q:** The Calamarain (m)(s)
**Allegiance:** Unnamed impersonating aliens (m)(s)
**Tin Man:** Tin Man/Gomtuu (s)

### Season 4

**Future Imperfect:** Unnamed species/Barash (s)
**The Loss:** Unnamed Two-dimensional space-faring species
**Clues:** The Paxans (s)
**Galaxy's Child:** Unnamed Space-whale
**Identity Crisis:** Unnamed DNA parasite (m)
**The Nth Degree:** The Cytherians (s)

### Season 5

**Darmok:** Unnamed El-Adrel Beast (m)
**Power Play:** Unnamed electromagnetic entities (m)(s)
**Imaginary Friend:** Unnamed energy lifeform (s)
**Time's Arrow, Part I:** The Devidians (m)(s)

### Season 6

**Realm of Fear:** Unnamed Subspace microbes
**Schisms:** Unnamed Solanogen-based lifeforms (m)(s)
**Aquiel:** Unnamed shape-shifting predator (m)(s)
**Timescape:** Unnamed quantum singularity aliens (s)

### Season 7

**Liaisons:** The Lyaraans (s)
**Interface:** Unnamed subspace creature (s)
**Sub Rosa:** Unnamed energy lifeform (m)(s)
**Emergence:** Unnamed Vertion-based lifeform

Comment: I want to know more about these *Borgms* and *Armusmsmsms*

Comment: The moment I started reading this answer, I knew that it could only be you. :)

Comment: I thought the "jellyfish" from EAF were sentient.

Comment: What about Where No One Has Gone Before from season 1? There was a lot of stuff they've met on that journey.

Comment: @doomista - [Memory Alpha](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Where_No_One_Has_Gone_Before_(episode)) mentions "energy beings" in the weird blue space thingy, but I can't see anything in [the script](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/106.txt) to indicate that that's what they are...

Comment: Was tehre not also one episode where they had a mining station or so (federation run) where the drones inside (some sort of mining drones) suddenly became sentient? (not sure if that counts as "life" or not).

Comment: @Thomas - This is TNG: The Quality of Life. The Exocomps appear to become sentient. I wouldn't describe them as a lifeform though.

Comment: @Valorum Still, the Traveller was an entity unknown to the crew/viewer (since even Koscinski did not really knew who the Traveller was).